# Why isn't my method sorting my columns in my matrix the way I want it?

Tags: java, sorting, matrix, multidimensional-array, keyword

I want to take a keyword entered by the user and sort that alphabetically then have the cols under it follow where the chars of the keyword are positioned after being sorted, example:

Before:

```
   K E Y S
   V V V X 
   D V G G 
   D F D V
```

After:

```
   E K S Y
   V V X V
   V D G G
   F D V D
```

My Output:

```
 E K S Y
 V V V X 
 D V G G 
 D F D V
```

My method that wont sort the information the way I want:

```
public String sortMatrix(String a [][]){



        System.out.println("\nAlphabetically rearranged: ");
        char[] key = polyCipher.getKeyword().toCharArray();
        char[] alphaKey = polyCipher.getKeyword().toCharArray();
        String alphaOut = "";

        //sort the key
        Arrays.sort(alphaKey);
        // set up temp array x

       //String a [][] = {{"V", "V", "V", "X"},{"D", "V", "G", "G"},{"D", "F", "D", "V"}};

        char[][] x = new char[a.length+1][];
        x[0] = alphaKey;

        for(int loop1 = 0; loop1 < a.length; loop1++){
            x[loop1+1] = new char[a[loop1].length];
            for (int loop2 = 0; loop2 < a[loop1].length; loop2++){
                x[loop1+1][loop2] = a[loop1][loop2].charAt(0);
            }
        }

        for(int loop1 = 0; loop1 < a.length; loop1++){
            x[loop1+1] = new char[a[loop1].length];
            for (int loop2 = 0; loop2 < a[loop1].length; loop2++){
                x[loop1+1][loop2] = a[loop1][loop2].charAt(0);
            }
        }


            /* x[0] = new char[]{'J', 'A', 'V', 'A'};
               x[1] = new char[]{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};
               x[2] = new char[]{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'};
               x[3] = new char[]{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}; */


            String [] strArray = new String[x[0].length];

            for (int loop1 = 0; loop1 < x.length; loop1++){
                for (int loop2 = 0; loop2 < x[0].length; loop2++){
                    if(strArray[loop2] == null){
                        strArray[loop2] = "";
                    }
                    strArray[loop2] += x[loop1][loop2];
                }
            }

            Arrays.sort(strArray);


            for (int loop1 = 0; loop1 < strArray.length; loop1++){
                for (int loop2 = 0; loop2 < strArray[loop1].length(); loop2++){
                    x[loop2][loop1] = strArray[loop1].charAt(loop2);
                }
            }

            Arrays.sort(key);
            alphaOut += "\n";
            for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
           //     keyOut += PHRASE_KEY[i] + " ";
               for (int j = 0; j < x[i].length; j++) {
                   alphaOut += x[i][j] + " ";
                }
               alphaOut += "\n";
            }

           return alphaOut.toUpperCase();


    }
```

Comment: Have you tried running this in a debugger and checking what actually got into your `strArray` before and after the sorting?

Comment: What is the actual result in contrast to the desired resut?

Comment: I've updated it with my output!

Comment: I think you want to sort the header and then sort the following rows of each column. so it will be like sort(header.sort(column[1..len])).

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code a little bit. I hope it could help you. I understand it should be changes in your code to make it work, but here is a working example :)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author Pasban
 */
public class sortmatrix {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] list = {"KVDD", "EVVF", "YVGD", "SXGV"};
        List<String> data = Arrays.asList(list);
        Collections.sort(data, new CustomComparator());
        int maxLen = 0;
        for (String str : data) {
            maxLen = Math.max(maxLen, str.length());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < maxLen; i++) {
            for (String str : data) {
                if (str.length() > i) {
                    System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String> {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return (o1.charAt(0) + "").compareTo(o2.charAt(0) + "");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

**

```
EKSY
VVXV
VDGG
FDVD
```

**

if the size of your columns is fixed, then:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] list = {"KVDD", "EVVF", "YVGD", "SXGV"};
        List<String> data = Arrays.asList(list);
        Collections.sort(data, new CustomComparator());
        int maxLen = 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < maxLen; i++) {
            for (String str : data) {
                System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! but the probelm is the matrix is generated at run time so by using the key as a seed to creat a random matrinx so  String[] list = {"KVDD", "EVVF", "YVGD", "SXGV"}; wont always be thos chars!

Comment: thats one of the things that have been confusing me

Comment: This is for only sorting part, you can create the matrix anyhow you want and then call the method. I didn't have the "polyCipher" so I used the example you have provided in your question. :)

Comment: So lets say I put this code in a method with the CustomComparator below it, what do I do to get the matrix I pass through = to the List?  String[] list = {a[0], a[1], a[2], a[4]};?

Answer (score 1):

I added two dimension sort. I used bubble sort. The output is exactly the same. The 2D sort is much better as you can have more that one char at your key part. The string sort just look at the first char, which it might look like a restriction.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author Pasban
 */
public class sortmatrix {

    public static String[] sortString(String[] inp) {
        List<String> data = Arrays.asList(inp);
        Collections.sort(data, new CustomComparator());
        return data.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

    public static String[][] sortString2D(String[][] inp) {

        String[][] out = inp;

        //inp.length number columns
        for (int i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) { // bubble sort
            for (int j = i + 1; j < inp.length; j++) {
                if (out[i][0].compareTo(out[j][0]) > 0) { // string comparison :)
                    String[] tmp;
                    tmp = out[i];
                    out[i] = out[j];
                    out[j] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }

        return out;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String[][] list2D = new String[][]{
            {"K", "V", "D", "D"},
            {"E", "V", "V", "F"},
            {"Y", "V", "G", "D"},
            {"S", "X", "G", "V"}
        };

        String[][] data2D = sortString2D(list2D);

        for (int j = 0; j < data2D[0].length; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < data2D.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(data2D[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println(" ----- ");


        String[] list = {"KVDD", "EVVF", "YVGD", "SXGV"};
        String[] data = sortString(list);

        int maxLen = data[0].length();
        for (int i = 0; i < maxLen; i++) {
            for (String str : data) {
                System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String> {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return (o1.charAt(0) + "").compareTo(o2.charAt(0) + "");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to make another string for this? Im sorry ive never used comparators so its hard to understand this but ill still try use it!

Comment: I provided two examples for you :) you can ignore the Comparator if your array is a 2D one. However, Comparator  is an easy way to sort arrays. As you can see, you can use bubble or other sorting method, but as long as Comparator does the job, it is more preferable.

Comment: Ok, put your project link here (dropbox, etc) so I can download it.

Comment: any helps greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here are the changes I made:

In your Matrix class, where you fill your matrix[][],

From:

```
matrix[i][j] = validChars.split("")[random].charAt(0);
```

to

```
matrix[i][j] =  validChars.charAt(random);
```

Notice that when you use **split("")**, the first item always will be an empty string. Empty string does not have any character, so getting the first character is meaningless. This caused me some errors, but I finally find it out. And hey, you can get the char by charAt() directly from the string, then why should you split it? :)

Next, whit in the sortMatrix(), you sort the keys with Arrays.sort(alphaKey); without sorting, or lets say connecting them to your column first. So the connection between your keys and content is destroyed. bellow is the correct way to sort your content along with your keys row.

I also added a rotateMatrix() method. If you want to displace the columns, you have to swap every column in each row one by one. Because of that I rotate the matrix and just swap the rows of the rotated matrix. Java keeps the matrix row by row, but we want it column by column (I hope you get the point :) )

```
public String[][] rotateMatrix(String inp[][]) {
    int L1 = inp.length;
    int L2 = inp[0].length;
    String[][] ret = new String[L2][L1];
    for (int i = 0; i < L1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < L2; j++) {
            ret[j][i] = inp[i][j];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

After the job is done, I rotate the matrix to inverse the rotation.

Here is the final sort matrix:

```
public String[][] sortMatrix(String a[][]) {

    System.out.println("\nAlphabetically rearranged: ");
    char[] key = polyCipher.getKeyword().toCharArray();

    //sort the key
    //Arrays.sort(alphaKey); // 

    //copy the array
    String[][] out = rotateMatrix(a);

    //inp.length number columns
    for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++) { // bubble sort
        for (int j = i + 1; j < key.length; j++) {
            if (key[i] > key[j]) { // string comparison :)
                //sort the header
                char c = key[i];
                key[i] = key[j];
                key[j] = c;
                //sort the column
                String[] tmp;
                tmp = out[i];
                out[i] = out[j];
                out[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.print("Sorted Key: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(key[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();

    /*
    for (int i = 0; i < out.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < out[0].length; j++) {
    System.out.print(out[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
    }*/

    return rotateMatrix(out);
}
```

The rest of your code is left untouched. You don't need customComprator anymore, remove it.

In my previous answers, if you have filled the first row of the input matrix to your sort matrix with your keys (inp[0][] = keys[], inp[1..length+1][]=a[0..length][]), it would have worked for you, regarding the example matrix provided there :D